# ngrx/store selector pattern with reselect

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I am comparing the current style of reducers implemented in the [ngrx example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app), with the previous ones, so to figure out pros and cons of each approach for a large-scale app.

What now is coded as:

```
export const getEntities = (state: State) => state.entities;
```

would have previously been written much like:

```
export function getEntities(state$: Observable<State>): Observable<IEntity[]> {
  return state$.select(state => state.entities)
}
```

While I do like the current succinct pattern that is enabled by use of [reselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect), I must say the old one appeals to me in that I can clearly see the type of data that is expected on output.

Since it was an Observable stream, it also allowed to do certain preliminary operations, like for example filtering:

```
export function getEntities(state$: Observable<State>): Observable<IEntity[]> {
  return state$.select(state => state.entities)
    .filter(state => state.isLoaded)
}
```

OTOH, in a fast-growing app, the older pattern becomes hardly managable and the amount of code bursts out rapidly.

I was wondering if there is an intermediate pattern that would get the best of these two worlds?

Comment: you can use several store.selects(...) and then do combinelatest to compute final values dependant on change in any of the underlying store parts. something like: http://onehungrymind.com/handle-multiple-angular-2-models-ngrx-computed-observables/

Comment: or if its commonly used operation, you could just create dedicated selector for it

Comment: is it possible to use store select in effect?